# How to convert a string in uint with a symbol in it in c#

Tags: c#, crash, int, uint

I have the problem that when I want to type in the console e.g. 0x12345678 it should convert it to an `uint` and save it as an `uint`, but it crashes on me and says that it has the wrong format.

```
uint zahl = 0x12345678;
uint zahl2;

Console.Write(zahl);    //Puts out into the Console: 305419896

zahl2 = Convert.ToUInt32(Console.ReadLine());   //I type in the Console 0x12345678 and after I press Enter it crashes

Console.Write(zahl2);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: you can't include the "0x" :             string input = "0x12345678";
            uint zahl2 = uint.Parse(input.Substring(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

Comment: What kind of exception do you have?

Comment: `Convert.ToUInt32("0x12345678", 16)` should work just fine. That being said, when dealing with user input, it's generally not recommended to use `Convert.ToXXXX` methods because you don't know if the user will enter a valid value. You should use `TryParse` methods instead. See [`uint.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint32.tryparse).

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me :D